# how to use toFixed method in react jsx

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use `toFixed` method in react but getting compile time error.

I wanted to round the result so after 2nd number there will be decimal, e.g. (79.222)

```
<div id='location-longitude'><strong>Percent survival   : </strong><p> 
<strong> {props.density.toFixed(2) /10 *50 }  </strong> % chance of 
 survival </p> 
</div>
 <br></br>
```

Getting an error saying `props.density.toFixed is not a function`. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the data type of `props.density`? Before the return of your render function where this jsx is, put in `console.log(typeof props.density)`. It's likely that `props.density` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: how do i convert to numeric type

Comment: what is the `typeof` value? a string? if so, you can do `parseInt()` to coerce it into a numeric. See docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem saying someState.toFixed is not a function.  I've fixed it by wrapping it in Number().

instead of:

```
props.density.toFixed(2)
```

change to:

```
Number(props.density).toFixed(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check type of `props.density`. Its must numeric type.
`toFixed` isn't a method of non-numeric variable types.

Answer (score 1):

change to numeric using `+` or Number()

```js
const num = '12.345'
console.log((+num).toFixed(2) /10 *50)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `props.density` is number. You may refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```js
var num = 123.456;
console.log(num.toFixed(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter the same problem. I fixed it by wrapping the value inside the Number First.
I want to limit the price to 2 decimal places, here we go

```
Number(price).toFixed(2)
```